# Set up EC2 instance to allow debugging on my local machine using PhpStorm

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, amazon-ec2, phpstorm, ssh-tunnel

I have a EC2 instance using nginx and a PHP test web application on it.

Currently every time I want to debug using PhpStorm I have to enter this command in my Ubuntu terminal:

```
sudo ssh -N -R 9000:localhost:9000 -i "devInstanceNginx.pem" ec2-user@test.co.uk
```

I am wondering what I can do so that I don't have to do that command.

(Note I will only generally debug from one of 2 devices if that makes a difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "Shell script" run configuration with this script. Configuration can be added via Run > Edit Configurations:
[image]